# If else jquery / javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the following scenario, the "Claim Win" button is suppose to show, but instead I get "Not enough points ...". Can someone explain why?

```
data[i].user_points = 1222
data[i].bid = 153
+(data[i].user_points < data[i].bid ?
    '<li class="list-group-item">\
        <span class="badge background-none"><a href="points"><button>Click here</button></a></badge></span>\
        Not enough points for this item.\
    </li>'
:

    (data[i].stime <= 0 ?
        ''
    :
        '<li class="list-group-item center"><button id="claim-'+data[i].item_id+'" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm claim">Claim Win</button></li>'
    )
)+
```

Edit*

This is what I get from the database

```
[
    {
        "id": "205",
        "item_id": "727",
        "winner_id": "62",
        "bid": "153",
        "status": "1",
        "date": "2015-09-05 05:53:12",
        "exp_date": "2015-09-07 05:53:12",
        "user_id": "296",
        "item_title": "neptun",
        "stime": 84178,
        "time_left": "0 d : 23 h : 22 m",
        "user_points": "1222",
        "user_thumb": "images\/ppic\/15x\/296.jpg?x=timestamp"
    }
]
```

Comment: Give more information, what is the plus tag before the code?

Comment: And the plus after the code?

Comment: You should use `if` statements instead of the conditional operators, and also be aware that JavaScript will *combine* the `data[i].bid = 153` with the next lines because you didn't use a semicolon. e.g. try this and see what happens (with an actual line break where I have the text `{linebreak}`: `var x = 123{linebreak}+'hello'`

Comment: Of course the `+` at the end makes the whole thing a syntax error.

Comment: Actually the conditional operators are probably OK - although I would simplify their formatting - format them like a chain of `if`/`else if`/`else` statements - all at the same level - instead of introducing the extra set of parentheses and nesting on the second conditional.

Comment: that code is part of an unordered list <ul> that s why there are +. And the values are t being set with = 1222. I was just showing what the values retrieved from the db are

Comment: it s just a little weird because I m comparing two numbers. if I do user _ points > bid ... the button shows

Comment: You should show a complete, runnable piece of code and not excerpts. My comments and the other comments are based on the code you posted, which is either a syntax error (if the last `+` is there) or doesn't do what you expect (if the second and third lines actually follow one after the other as in the code you posted).

Comment: ok. I'll post a complete code a little later

Comment: The logic seems OK, you need to make a jsfiddle to see if something is changed in between.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ckpm65be/ ... hope this helps. I also added the json encoded data in my edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't an answer to your question, but I wanted to follow up on my comment about the conditional operator formatting, and the only way to show a formatted code sample is in an answer.

When you use a series of conditional operators as your code has, it's best to format them as a flat *chain* of operators instead of *nested* operators. A good way to illustrate this is with a similar use of `if` statements:

```js
if( a == 1 ) {
    b = 'one';
} else {
    if( a == 2 ) {
        b = 'two';
    } else {
        if( a == 3 ) {
            b = 'three;
        } else {
            b = 'other';
        }
    }
}
```

Most developers and style guides would recommend reformatting that to remove the nesting and extra braces:

```js
if( a == 1 ) {
    b = 'one';
} else if( a == 2 ) {
    b = 'two';
} else if( a == 3 ) {
    b = 'three;
} else {
    b = 'other';
}
```

This is logically exactly the same code, but it's much more clear in this form. (Of course you could alternatively use a `switch` statement or perhaps an array for this particular code; it's just an example of formatting a chain of `if`/`else` statements.)

The same principle applies to conditional operators. You could write code like that `if` statement using nested conditionals with lots of parentheses:

```js
b = (
    a == 1 ? (
        'one'
    ) : (
        a == 2 ? (
            'two'
        ) : (
            a == 3 ? (
                'three'
            ) : (
                'other'
            )
        )
    )
);
```

(This isn't exactly the same as the code formatting you were using; it's a contrived example to make a point.)

Just as with the `if` statements, it's better to flatten it out:

```js
b = (
    a == 1 ? 'one' :
    a == 2 ? 'two' :
    a == 3 ? 'three' :
    'other'
);
```

Again it's logically the same code, just much easier to follow this way.

In fact, I had a heck of a time just getting the syntax correct with the nested version - I had to use a syntax-checking editor and fiddle with it a lot - but the flat version came out right the first time.